# Making copies of large lists to trigger change detection for pure pipes in Angular 2 affecting performance

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array `a` containing 50,000+ objects and I have a pipe which takes this array `a` and transforms this into some output which is then displayed in the view.

The pipe is pure meaning that only when the reference to array `a` changes will it re-evaluate.

I have a method `modifyArray` which adds/removes some elements from array `a`. When completed I would like the pipe to be re-evaluated so that the view re-renders.

Because of the way that Angular enforces immutability, the only option I have for the pipe to be re-evaluated is for the method `modifyArray` to return a copy of array `a` with the changes applied, so that Angular can detect that the reference has changed and trigger the pipe, something like this:

```
modifyArray(a: T[]): T[] {

  a.push(b);
  a.slice(c);

  return [...a];
}
```

However for such an array with 50,000+ elements, there is a real performance degradation when making a copy of the array.

I would have expected that explicitly triggering change detection after invocation of this method, for example by calling `ApplicationRef.tick()` or `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`, would allow Angular to figure out that the array has been modified, but this is not the case:

```
this.a = modifyArray(a);

this.applicationRef.tick();
```

Making a copy of the array is not an option as the data set is too large. Making the pipe not pure is also not an option as the transformation the pipe applies to the input is expensive.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of timeline showing that exactly _copying_ of the array is a bottleneck. I'm almost sure that the real problem is `ngFor` on updated array which causes DOM recreation for all elemets.

Comment: Also it would be great if you show some working example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: @Cristian okay thank you

Comment: i have a same problem, how do u resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 change detection only checks object references. It doesn't depend how often it checks but only that it doesn't look inside arrays ;-), this is why explicitly invoke change detection doesn't have any effect.

Perhaps doing change detection yourself in `ngDoCheck` with an `IterableDiffer` might help in your case but your question doesn't provide enought information to know for sure.

You can use the `*ngFor` directive as example https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/14ee75924b6ae770115f7f260d720efa8bfb576a/modules/%40angular/common/src/directives/ng_for.ts#L122

Comment: One thing I'm unsure of is how to tell Angular to re-render the view from the `ngDoCheck` method. If I'm not mistaken, the fact that the pipes are pure means that the **only** way to trigger them is by changing the object reference, and therefore anything I do in the `ngDoCheck` won't re-render the view.

Comment: Sorry, somehow forgot about the "pipe" part. What you could to is to use an additional parameter that you pass to the pipe (like `someValue | myPipe:someParam` where you increment the value of the `someParam` property every time after the array was modify. This also would cause the pipe to be called again. You could also use an impure pipe and use `IterableDiffer` inside the pipe to check if some actual work has to be done. An impure pipe would be called like `ngDoCheck` (to close the cycle with my original answer).

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure on your situation, but usually displaying 50 000 elements is not the best idea, since no human would be able to do anything with such a massive array anyway. So first thing you can try to do is processing more data on the server and return the part that is really needed (like e.g. first 20 entries filtered by some search field).

If that does not work for you for some reason (though it's interesting to know why not) you can just try processing your array yourself and remember the result in a variable on the component. Angular2 team has made a [decision](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe-) to not include `filter` or `sorting` pipe because of performance issue. Their advise is to store the data required yourself. I.e. when you get the array (or update later), process it and store the result in a separate variable that is available to html via component.

Further on you can extract this to a separate service or component if you need to reuse it. You can read about reasoning in the link I provided above.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article. That was actually how this application was architected, but there are so many toggles/filters/visibility options that re-calculating the data programatically resulted in a very un-clean, un-uniform solution. Implementing these filters as pipes works perfectly in this case as the logic is contained within each pipe and are handled by the framework only when required. I agree with you that 50,000 elements is too much, but it's a pretty specific use-case, I'll have to think about what else is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

your array is changed and your pipe is not re-evaluating, **this is limitation of pure pipe.**, Pure pipe is wrong selection here.

In Angular2 Change detection will only run if it is **primitive changes or reference it self changes**. here you are changing Element of the Array. so what happens here Array get changed but reference didn't changed. so Angular2 isn't aware that it should re-run change detection and re-run the ui.

**Solution is:**   ***Impure Pipe***. This pipe will listen to every events and re-run pipe for you. this pipe may be disadvantage in your case bcz you have large amount of data in array this may cause a performance issue, but *it will work for you*.

**How to create Impure Pipe**: just add `pure:false` in your pipe Decoration.

```
 @Pipe({
        name: 'my-custom-pipe',
        pure: false
     })
```

Comment: Unfortunately using an impure pipe is not an option as their computation is expensive considering the size of the data set. Making the pipe impure means that un-related changes will cause the pipes to be re-evaluated unnecessarily.